# Python pandas Get daily: MIN MAX AVG results of datasets

Tags: python, pandas, csv, max, min

Using Python with pandas to export data from a database to csv.Data looks like this when exported. Got like 100 logs/day so this is pure for visualising purpose:

| time | Buf1 | Buf2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2022 19:15:56 | 12 | 3 |
| 12/12/2022 18:00:30 | 5 | 18 |
| 11/12/2022 15:15:08 | 12 | 3 |
| 11/12/2022 15:15:08 | 10 | 9 |

Now i only show the "raw" data into a csv but i am in need to generate for each day a min. max. and avg value. Whats the best way to create that ? i've been trying to do some min() max() functions but the problem here is that i've multiple days in these csv files. Also trying to manupilate the data in python it self but kinda worried about that i'll be missing some and the data will be not correct any more.

I would like to end up with something like this:

| time | buf1_max | buf_min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2022 | 12 | 3 |
| 12/12/2022 | 12 | 10 |

[image: How the end result should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, step by step.

```
In [27]: df['time'] = df['time'].astype("datetime64").dt.date

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
         time  Buf1  Buf2
0  2022-12-12    12     3
1  2022-12-12     5    18
2  2022-11-12    12     3
3  2022-11-12    10     9

In [29]: df = df.set_index("time")

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
            Buf1  Buf2
time
2022-12-12    12     3
2022-12-12     5    18
2022-11-12    12     3
2022-11-12    10     9

In [31]: df.groupby(df.index).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
Out[31]:
           Buf1           Buf2
            min max  mean  min max  mean
time
2022-11-12   10  12  11.0    3   9   6.0
2022-12-12    5  12   8.5    3  18  10.5
```

Comment: Thanks ! seems to work but one question i lost the timestamp column somehow how can i add the timestamps to the csv?

Comment: You can really add timestamp because you have grouped data by date. How would one line of grouped data would look like if you would have more than one line being aggregated?

Comment: So i would like to have just a simple time stamp for each row. For example all grouped data who has the date 12/12/2022 show all there min,max,avg. And in the first column put the timestamp without hours. something like that i guess? Except you solution as shown in the last step (OUT[31]). but the timestamp dissapeard here

Comment: Can you provide complete example how you image that table should look like? You can take my text output of last table, edit it, and add to the question. So it is clear what you expect.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing answer, 've added the wanted output to the question

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the difference.

Comment: The output when using your solution is missing the timestamp column. How do i add the timestamp to it?

Comment: It does have date "timestamp" in index. You can use reset_index() if that is what you want. 
But I am really not sure what you expect.

Comment: Alright Thanks now it works ! Sorry for confusing kinda new to stack.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `pivot_table` for simplification of grouping data (keep in mind to convert 'time' column to `datetime64` format as suggested:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.pivot_table(
    index='time', 
    values=['Buf1', 'Buf2'], 
    aggfunc={'Buf1':[min, max, np.mean], 'Buf2':[min, max, np.mean]}
)
```

You can add any aggfunc as you wish.

Comment: I guess the downside is that it becomes more complex if you don't know the exact number of columns to aggregate?

Comment: @Aidis https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html Basically, it is optional parameter so you dont need exact columns to aggregate

Comment: Ok, that should work. Upvoted.